# How to make the wavy underline extend cover all the characters in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I tried to use wavy underline to highlight full sentences, but it seems that it will miss certain characters (short ones and those at the end of the underline). Is this expected behavior or a bug in Google Chrome (everything works ok in Firefox)?

[image]

If this is expected behaviour (I understand that the wavy underlines for very short characters may not seem very appealing), how do I workaround that to get wavy underline (preferably without resorting to background image substitutes) on the full extent of the text?

```css
.dotted,
.wavy {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-color: blue;
}

.dotted {
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
}

.wavy {
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
}

div {
  font-family: "Times New Roman"
}

div {
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

.ok {
  border-color: green
}

.problem {
  border-color: red
}

.using-sans {
  font-family: sans
}
```

```html
<div class=ok>
  <p>
    The dotted underline correctly underlines all characters:
    <span class=dotted>works ok</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    As well as single characters:
    <span class=dotted>d</span>
  </p>
</div>


<div class="problem">
  <p>
    But the vawy underline misses the last character:
    <span class=wavy>does not work ok</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    And does not work for some single characters:
    <span class=wavy>d</span>
  </p>
</div>


<div class="ok">
  <p>
    Suprisingly, it does work for others:
    <span class=wavy>W</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="problem">
  <p>
    Which seem to depend on the length of the glyph, as the lowercase version of "w" does not work:
    <span class=wavy>w</span>
  </p>
</div>


<div class="ok using-sans">
  <p>
    Unless we change the font:
    <span class=wavy>w</span>
  </p>
</div>


<div class="problem using-sans">
  <p>
    But again, it will only work for some characters:
    <span class=wavy>p</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Edit: I found what seems to be a related [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=668042#c5) which explains that

> The Chromium implementation for rendering a wavy underline is to
>   "round down to the nearest wavelength"

Comment: an idea in case you want a custom implementation where you will have full control: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199850/8620333

Comment: I like that, the idea seems very useful for the ease of customization of the wave shape (I do not like the default one, but don't want to use images either)!

Comment: let me know if you face issue adjusting the existing code, I will then add an answer with an updated version that will work here.