# CSS Animated wavy line not displaying properly in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations, keyframe

I have created a simple animated wavy line to use as a divider on one of my websites. Looks perfect in safari but it displays strange in Chrome.

Here's the safari screenshot: 
[image]

Here's the chrome screenshot: 
[image]

The safari one is perfect for me, but it seems chrome isn't liking it.

I have tried adding ALL vendor prefixes to the start of the selectors and various places but I cant seem to fix the issue.

Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here's a [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/shaun-taylor/pen/GRRmjQG) and here's a code snippet:

```css
.wavy-line {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.wavy-line:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  width: calc(100% + 27px);
  font-size: 4em;
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
  text-decoration-color: #25173A;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  animation: animate .9s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: animate .9s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% { left: -0px; }
  100% { left: -30px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% { left: -0px; }
  100% { left: -30px;}
}

.wavy-line-green:before { text-decoration-color: #56AE5F; }
.wavy-line-blue:before { text-decoration-color: #1FB5D1; }
.wavy-line-yellow:before { text-decoration-color: #F9B930; }
```

```html
<div class="wavy-line wavy-line-green" data-text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>

<div class="wavy-line wavy-line-blue" data-text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>

<div class="wavy-line wavy-line-yellow" data-text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
```

Comment: only the last one is bad

Comment: True, but when I remove them all and only have one on the screen, that one is bad too.... Also on my site I have multiple iterations of them on one page and they are all 'bad'

Comment: well, you are also relying on a hacky method to create waves. Consider using SVG or draw is using other CSS techniques

Comment: and idea with CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199850/8620333

Comment: Problem is with your top which are giving` -` value

Answer (score 3):

I will consider a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199850/8620333) to draw the waves using CSS and then you can easily animate them. You simply need to adjust the CSS variable to control the shape:

```css
.wave {
  --c:red;   /* Color */
  --t:5px;   /* Thickness */
  --h:50px;  /* Height  */
  --w:120px; /* Width  */
  --p:13px;  /* adjust this to correct the position when changing the other values*/
  
  margin:5px auto;
  width:calc(var(--w)*4);
  height:calc(var(--h) + 10px);
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.wave:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  padding:5px 0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:200%;
  bottom:0;
  
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% calc(100% + var(--p)), transparent 47%, var(--c) 50% calc(50% + var(--t)),transparent calc(52% + var(--t))),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at 50% calc(0%   - var(--p)), transparent 47%, var(--c) 50% calc(50% + var(--t)),transparent calc(52% + var(--t)));
    
  background-size:var(--w) var(--h);
  background-position:calc(var(--w)/2) calc(-1*(var(--h)/2)),0px calc(var(--h)/2);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-origin:content-box;
  
  animation:move 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
   transform:translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>

<div class="wave" style="--w:140px;--h:40px;--p:13px; --t:8px;--c:purple"></div>


<div class="wave" style="--w:100px;--h:30px;--p:14px;--t:10px;--c:green;"></div>

<div class="wave" style="--w: 64px;--h: 22px;--p: 11px;--t: 7px;--c: orange;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - Sorry about the late reply... I can just about get this to work but the lines all look jaggy and if you look at the yellow one in your example (and the rest) they all seem to have a black outline? Would you know why this would be at all? :)

Comment: @ShaunTaylor can you share a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Yeah sure, just added it ad an answer so I can show you a screenshot...

Comment: @ShaunTaylor no don't use the answer section, simply copy the link of the image here

Comment: Here's an image of what I'm seeing - no matter what I try, the yellow line at the bottom (your solution) doesn't look as smooth as my previous solution - it has some sort of black outline around it... http://staging.erewash-partnership.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Screenshot-2019-11-13-at-20.23.41.png

Here's a pen which im fiddling around with... obviously best views in safari lol! :) https://codepen.io/shaun-taylor/pen/oNNajeQ?editors=1100

Comment: @ShaunTaylor I can see your deleted answer, let me check

Comment: @ShaunTaylor you somehow reached the limitation of my solution. Since it's about radial-gradient it's difficult to have it as thin as you want. Will try to see if I can find a better solution

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help :) Ive found a javascript solution, I just need to centre the wavy line in the middle instead of left aligning it! - https://codepen.io/shaun-taylor/pen/vYBmqEj

Comment: @ShaunTaylor `text-align: center;` on the container