# Different results on border/border-radius on Firefox vs Chromium

Tags: html, css, border, border-radius

I am using the following CSS to generate very simple 2d river shapes:

```css
.river-left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 20px rgb(0, 140, 255);
  border-color: rgb(0, 140, 255) transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  align-self:center;
  margin-top: 19px;
}

.river-right {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 20px rgb(0, 140, 255);
  border-color: rgb(0, 140, 255) transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="river-left"></div><div class="river-right"></div>
```

In Firefox, the following HTML `<div class="river-left"></div><div class="river-right"></div>` then generates the shape you can see in the following image:

[image]

But in Chromium, it looks completely different (worse):

[image]

I tried using -webkit- properties to resolve this but I couldn't work out how to do so. I realise that the more conventional approach to making these shapes would be to use SVG. I think I may switch to SVG (even though this is only a quick mock-up of an idea either way) but it would be nice to know how to resolve this discrepancy.

Comment: I've switched to using SVG+Javascript to create wavy lines so there's no urgency to solve this.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199850/8620333